# Is bezout identity a double implication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

The question is if given two integers a and b, if I find a pair of integers $x$ and $y$ so $ax + by = 1$, is it always true that $gcd(a,b) = 1$?

This comes from a problem in which I had to prove that the system

$x \equiv 1 \quad (mod N)$

$x\equiv 2 \quad (mod N^2-1)$

has a solution without solving it. I tried to solve it by proving that $N$ and $N^2-1$ are coprimes and I got that $N*k -(N^2+1)*q = 1$ for some integers $k,q$

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Well, if $d$ divides both $a,b$ then it clearly divides $ax+by$.

Comment: "I could not manage to write the right symbol". Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ .

Answer (score 1):

If $ax+by=d$ then $\gcd(x,y)$ divides $d$.  In this case, $d=1$, which forces $\gcd(x,y)=1$.